# Noob having trouble connecting to the Infura Mainnet

Tags: web3j, infura

I've been attempting to run a script from my terminal, and have been getting this error:

> Error: CONNECTION ERROR: Couldn't connect to node https://mainnet.infura.io.

I've installed Web3j on my local machine, and unless I'm missing something, I've successfully generated a token (though it'd be great if Infura's site had some way to confirm that the digits I previously saved when doing so are correct).

So from here, I tried the the following command:

```
Web3j web3 = Web3j.build(new InfuraHttpService("https://morden.infura.io/your-token"));
```

And it's telling me:

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

I'm so green that I'm unsure where the specific syntax error may be - or even if running this command was the right step to take.  I swapped out "your-token" for the 20 digits I understood my token to be comprised of, to make sure that's clear.

Appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Comment: You gave two unrelated errors. One was about connecting to mainnet.infura.io, and one was a syntax error about code that connects to a completely different domain. Could you pick one issue you want help with and then share your full code and the full error message?

Comment: Yes, I need help connecting to the Infura mainnet, evidently, as that's the error being thrown.  Here's the script:

Comment: I ran 'npm run check-wallets' in my terminal after ssh-ing into our instance.  What I believe to be the script itself is below:

Comment: {
  "name": "ourthing-logic-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "API with business logic endpoints",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --watch src/ --watch config/ --exec babel-node -- src/server.js",
    "lint": "eslint src/",
    "check-wallets": "babel-node bin/checkWallets.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/ourthing/ourthing-logic-api.git"
  },
  ....and then a bunch of dependencies.

Comment: How does npm relate? That's for JavaScript code, but you're using Web3j, which is a Java library?

Comment: npm was the command i was told to use to run the script by the person who wrote it.  I thought that maybe I needed to install Web3j locally in order to make the script run, I guess?

Comment: You might want to talk to the person who wrote the script.

Comment: Trying to do so